# How to display information in small box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: Attachment]

I have added **[?]** in right side of the form to show information about respective fields. I want to show information in small box after clicking **[?]**. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hide the box with display:none; then trigger to show it when the user click the [?] , something like this `$('#info').click(function(){ $('#infobox').show(); }); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use **[tipsy](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy)** for this

Comment: link broken throws err 500.

Answer (score 3):

Given that your information is in an HTML element like so:

```
 <div class="info-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscit elit
      Cras in.
 </div>
```

And your CSS has a rule like:

```
 .info-box { display: none; }
```

Then your jQuery code will look like this:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.help').on('click', function(){
            $('.info-box').show();
      })
 });
```

If I had seen the actual HTML, I could give you a more specific answer; perhaps including a close button in the upper-right (which you would implement with the [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method) and a simple system to find out which info-box you need to show.

Until then, this should get you on the right track.

### Edit

Given your HTML, I would suggest this solution:

Wrap all your help elements inside a `<div>` inside your table-cell, like so:

```
<div class="help">
    <div class="info-box">
         <a href="#" class="close-button">&times;</a>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscit elit
         Cras in.
    </div>
    <a class='help-button' href='#' title="Click to know more">[?]</a>
</div>
```

The minimal CSS you will need, will look like this:

```
.help {
    display:  inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.info-box {
    width:    150px;
    position: absolute;
    right:    -170px;
}
```

As for the jQuery code, it's going to be very simple:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.help-button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.info-box').show();
  });
  
  $('.close-button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.info-box').hide();
  });
});
```

I have made a better styled example for your, here:

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/iboyur/1)</kbd>

Comment: I don't think I can have access to this page without being a user, unfortunately; just post your HTML and it will suffice.

Comment: <tr>
     <td class="textalign_right">Page Title :</td>
     <td class="space_in_table">&nbsp;</td>
     <td>
           <input type='text' class="textinput" name="page_title" value=''/><br />
           <a href="javascript:" title="Click to know more">[?]</a>
           <div class="validation_error"></div>
     </td>
</tr>

Comment: I edited my answer adding more information and a working example.

Answer (score 2):

I think your requirements are so simple that I wouldn't use a framework to solve it.
Just put a hidden element next to the box and show it on click

```
<div style="display:none" id="helpText" class="helptTextBox">
    <div class="closeIcon">X</div>
</div>

$('#questionBox').click(
  function(){
    $("#helpText").show();
  });



$('.closeIcon').click(
    function(){
        $(this).closest(".helptTextBox").hide();
    });
```